# How can I open a new tab in Chrome from the Cr-48 shell?

Tags: google-chrome-os, crosh

I have a `Cr-48` (Google Chrome notebook) in developer mode and can get to a bash shell by running the "shell" command in crosh. What I would like to do is open a new tab to a specific URL by entering a command in that shell. For example, I'd like to run something like "chrome http://www.google.com" in the shell to open a new tab showing Google Search.

There is an /opt/google/chrome/chrome binary in the root filesystem, but it does not do what I want.

Background info:

I [installed Perl, Vim, and TwitVim](http://mortonfox.livejournal.com/807025.html) on the Cr-48. The only things that don't work are commands that launch a browser from TwitVim. To do that, TwitVim does a system() call to run chrome with the URL as the argument. Until I figure out which binary to run on the `Cr-48` to do that, this functionality won't work.

Comment: I am kind of wondering if this question should be posted on Super User instead. However, there is a coding component to it here since I am looking for something I can invoke via system().

Comment: What happens if you simply type `open http://www.google.com` ? That works on some systems, like macs.

Comment: It says "bash: open: command not found".

Comment: "open" is not magical in the Mac bash shell either. It runs /usr/bin/open. But yes, that's the kind of thing I was hoping to find on the Cr-48.

Comment: Can I ask you how did you installed those programs Perl, Vim on Cr-48?
What program or command did you use?
Thank you.

Comment: In my question above, I linked to my blog entry that describes how I installed the programs. Basically, I used packages from Arch Linux but there are a few other steps, such as switching the Cr-48 to developer mode and making the filesystem writable.

Comment: find out where the binary app executable is, and just type that in. on mac it would be something like Applications/Google\ Chrome.app